Apache RewriteCond multiple ip not working
I have a problem with my .htaccess file which looks like this :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10x\.x\.x\.[0-255]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.xx\.[0-255] 
#[OR]
###RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^15\.x\.xxx\.[0-255]
#[OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.[0-255] [OR]
#[OR]


###RewriteCond expr "-R '1x.x.x.x'"
###RewriteCond expr "-R '8.x.x.x'" [OR]
###RewriteCond expr "-R '9x.x.x.x/25'" [OR]
###RewriteCond expr "-R 'x.1x.x.x'"

RewriteRule ^.*$  error.html [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

And what I'd like to do is that

if people try to access my site outside the ip addresses (ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4), they'll be redirected to the error.html page and, if not, to the correct index.php page, but I can't manage it in my combinations.

After redirect http to https request becauce when I type http://example.com, I get a 403 error.


Thanks in advance

There is nothing in that which might redirect from http to https, so we cannot say anything about that.

You certainly need to check the address before you apply the more general rule rewriting to index.php. And you'd have to stop the rewriting engine from looping again, otherwise error.html would get rewritten to index.php too ...

And what are those "x"es doing in the patterns meant to match the remote address? An address cannot contain an "x". And "x" does not have any special magical meaning in a regular expression.

Thanks @arkascha. I just have "x" so as not to expose the ip addresses. Otherwise they are IP addresses like 192.168.0.1 etc.... For the 2., I wanted to say that I'd like the user to be able to reach my site in https if he types http://example.com and not get a 403 error.

Certainly you want to redirect your users from http to https. But we cannot help fixing something that does not exist. You have to implement a redirection for that. Put it first, so further up in that configuration file. You will find many existing examples for that here on SO.

And check those [OR] tags again you commented out. As your code looks now you have a syntax error in your configuration file. The last not commented [OR] is followed by a rule, not a condition, which makes no sense. Keep in mind that you need to monitor your http server's error log file when implementing such rules. No way around that. In that file you will get valuable hints in such cases.

Thank you very much for your clarification. In the logs I noticed that some users' devices were returning IPV6 instead of IPV4. Those who had IPV4s were able to access them and others were not on the same network.
